# Are functions that take a parameter of unknown type allowed in D?

Tags: d

Is it possible to pass a function a parameter of an unknown type in D. I would like to pass a parameter that could be either a struct, char[], string or int. Is this possible? I am new to D so please forgive my ignorance. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet you are [looking for templates](http://dlang.org/template.html).

D has a great [language reference](http://dlang.org/spec.html) that is free online.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, besides templates is the [std.variant](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_variant) module. Its functionality can be very useful in some situations like interfacing dynamic languages. For example some of the packages on http://code.dlang.org dealing with data languages (like [YAML](http://code.dlang.org/packages/dyaml), [JSON](http://code.dlang.org/packages/std_data_json) and [SDL](http://code.dlang.org/packages/sdlang-d)) use [Algebraic](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_variant#.Algebraic) for representing nodes (or values) inside documents.